# Loop with delay period

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have a TextView and I want each second to highlight another letter in the word.

For example:
 **h** e l l o - h **e** l l o - h e **l** l o - h e l **l** o - h e l l **o**

What I have done:

```
int i = 0;
String text;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void spanText(String txt) {
    text = txt;
    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Spannable spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
        StyleSpan style = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        spannable.setSpan(style, i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        bestResult.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        i++;
        if(i < text.length())
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I can see only the last letter highlighted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `spanText()` send runnable for each letter in short time. Assuming your code it should only start from first letter. Try to remove cycle there and send one runnable only.

Comment: @andrew Thank you! It works! Do you have any ideas to make this code more efficient? I think this code is very inefficient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
String text;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void spanText(String txt) {
    text = txt;
    handler.post(runnable);

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Spannable spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
        StyleSpan style = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        spannable.setSpan(style, i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        bestResult.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        i++;
        if(i < text.length())
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Do you have any ideas to make this code more efficient? I think this code is very inefficient..

Comment: why do you think so ?? I think this one is better than using sleep or timer

Comment: because I use here class-level variables, just for a little thing.

Comment: Which one is the class level variable? :O

Comment: They seems member variable here... am i missing something?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. But I still think that variable like "i" or "text" should be within some method =\